# How do I display knockoutjs.mapping data in my template?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using knockout's mapping plugin, how would I go about displaying the information from and array of JSON object's in my template.?

```javascript
//Example JSON data.
JSON = [{'title':'title of first object', 
         'content':'content of first json object'}, 
         {'title':'title of second object', 'content': 'content of second json object'}]

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

var data = $.getJSON('/post/.json', function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
});
```

I'm able to access the objects via viewModel() and viewModel()[0].title() using Console in Chrome but not sure how to bind this date to my template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you receive your data, you would need to call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)`.

In your HTML, you can bind against your data like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
     <li>
          <span data-bind="text: title"></span>: 
          <span data-bind="text: content"></span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YkT6p/

Comment: Thanks RP, I was missing data-bind="foreach: $data".